# Uso de "pistola" como adjetivo para irritado ou enfezado

Tags: significado, girias

Recentemente na Copa do Mundo de Futebol de 2018, a seleção brasileira adotou o *[Canarinho Pistola](https://twitter.com/canariopistola)* como mascote.

O que me causou estranheza foram diferentes menções ao fato de que o canarinho possui uma [expressão “pistola"](https://extra.globo.com/esporte/copa-2018/entenda-fenomeno-do-canarinho-pistola-mascote-da-selecao-que-bomba-nas-redes-sociais-22529420.html), como se fosse significado de estar enfezado ou irritado. Naturalmente consultei dicionários, mas o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pistola), p.ex. não parece corroborar esta tese.

Em suma, O que significa *pistola* quando usado como adjetivo?

Comment: Pistola *é* usado como gíria para irritado, furioso. Era usado em conjunção à imagem de Bola — do programa Pânico na TV —, em fóruns anônimos da internet vários anos atrás. Em 2016, a piada já abandonada voltou a ser forçada em grupos de Facebook e se propagou novamente, dessa vez se popularizando. Quanto à história da gíria antes de Bola, não se sabe; é provável que ele próprio tenha inventado.

Comment: @William, interessante, não conhecia este uso, talvez por não assistir o programa mecnionado. Tens como adicionar alguma referência e transformar seu comentário em uma resposta?

Comment: @William, não seria o caso de postar teu comentário como resposta?

Comment: Atualmente tenho muito escutado "full pistola", quando a pessoa está muito irritada :).

Comment: Escuto a expressão tem uns 2 anos em streams de jogos "Ihhh ficou pistola." - "Ihhh está bravo". E variações como "Ta AK47.", quanto maior o calibre maior a fúria, aparentemente. Não que eu encoraje o uso da gíria nem nada :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pistola* é usado como [gíria para irritado, furioso](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/pistola/10476/). Era usado em conjunção à imagem de [Bola¹](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxqM-fHw0es) — do programa Pânico na TV —, em fóruns anônimos da internet vários anos atrás, e também em grupos de facebook inspirados nesses mesmos fóruns anônimos. Em [2016, a piada, já abandonada, voltou a ser forçada em grupos de Facebook e se propagou novamente](http://forum.jogos.uol.com.br/da-onde-surgiu-essa-giria-pistola_t_3875949), dessa vez se popularizando. Em 2017/2018, anos depois, ela chega às grandes massas; como de costume, atrasadamente.

Quanto à história da gíria antes de Bola, não se sabe; é provável que ele próprio tenha inventado.

No que tange à semântica da gíria, talvez se trate do estrondo das armas de fogo, assim como pessoas furiosas tendem a produzir barulho desagradável; ou simplesmente por ficar quente. Porventura ainda, talvez seja um desenvolvimento de "*pisto*", uma corruptela de palavrão (deve-se notar que em TV aberta o uso de palavrão é restringido).

¹ Pode-se perceber que o vídeo é de 2010, portanto o uso do linguajar é anterior a essa data.

P.S.: o uso da palavra é considerado inculto — por motivos óbvios —, e ridículo — pois os que a usavam originalmente consideram uma gíria antiga e ultrapassada.

Comment: «talvez seja um desenvolvimento de "pisto", uma corruptela de palavrão» Qual palavrão? Não conheço essa palavra, pisto, nem imagino que palavrão a possa ter originado.

Comment: @ANeves Pisto é a corruptela, não o palavrão em si, remova o ‘s’.

Answer (score 2):

Pistola, é usando quando alguém esta fora de si, irritado/zangado ou coisas do tipo.
Vou te dar um exemplo:

> Não levei o lixo para fora, e minha mãe veio *PISTOLA* pra cima de
> mim.
>
> [Também tem esse aqui do panico na tv](https://youtu.be/wxqM-fHw0es)

Comment: Interessante Rafael! Costumas ouvir esta expressão frequentemente? Em qual região do Brasil?

Comment: Sim sim, é comum no interior do Rio(Volta Redonda, Barra Mansa, etc).
Até em SP, eu ja ouvi falar algumas vezes.

Comment: Interessante, eu só ouvi agora na cobertura da Copa do Mundo e mesmo assim pela repercussão na mídia.

Comment: temas umas referencias antigas, mas ficou mais popular agora.
aqui um exemplo https://youtu.be/wxqM-fHw0es

Answer (score 1):

Eu queria deixar isso como comentário. Também me intriga esse uso, mas recentemente um colunista do jornal Folha de São Paulo abordou o assunto. "O país dos(as) pistolas" de sérgio rodrigues. Não é uma referência, mas achei interessante. Ele especula ter relação com *pissed off*.

[O país dos(as) pistolas, Folha de São Paulo, 2018-06-07](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/sergio-rodrigues/2018/06/o-pais-dosas-pistolas.shtml)

Comment: Com certeza essa gíria vem do termo em inglês “pissed off”. Acredito que essa gíria começou em São Paulo, que ao meu ver é uma das regiões mais desenvolvidas do Brasil.